# How can I retrieve the URI of an ontology from a Jena Model?

Tags: jena, semantic-web, jena-rules

this is a very simple question, but I don't seem to find an answer in forums/docs.

I have an OntModel that imports other ontologies, and I simply want to retrieve the URI of the root ontology.
Looking directly at statements won't work in my case: some ontologies import "URLs", whose corresponding document has a different URI.
Is there some method to simply retrieve the URI of an ontology ?

Answer (score 2):

easy :)

```
model.getNsPrefixURI("");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I assume this simple gets the the `xmlns` attribute, which isn't followed by any identifier like `xmlns:owl`. I am wondering why this only takes the source ontology into account and not any other imported ontologies.

Comment: What if it has xml:base and not the empty xmlns:  (ex: http://topbraid.org/schema/schema.rdf)?